# Restrict single url for a single IP

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, restrict

I have denied all IPs except few in `htaccess` file.

Now I want a *new* IP to allow access only 1 particular url (it is not a html page but a page from `wordpress`). I do not want this IP to access other content of the website.

I do not want password protection as it will affect all other users.

Can we do something like that ?

Comment: put that file inside a directory and create a customized `htaccess` file for that directory

Comment: Thanks you for answering, 
It is not a html page but a page from wordpress (dynamic page/post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the new `ip` to the list of allowed ones, then restrict it to access all `uri`s except to the allowed one.

Assume that you want to deny access of the user with IP:`124.255.124.255`  to all urls except of `www.example.com/url-to-hide` .After granting access to all urls, Put the following code in `.htaccess` file of the root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^124\.255\.124\.255 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/url-to-hide$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Ormoz, thanks for Understanding my question, and giving me a workable solution.

Comment: Sorry for asking again. I under stand the first part. 

But if if the website url structure is like this : http://mysite/link-to-hide
How should I define in htaccess

Comment: @Kent I changed the answer a bit to clarify what should be done. Please tell me if it is not still clear.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome, please don't forget to mark the answer as `accepted` if it solved your problem ;-)

Comment: There is a tick below the `votes no`. votes no is currently `0` (top left of the answer) @Kent